# How do I download wine on 12.04

Tags: 12.04

can someone please tell me how to download wine so that I can open exe. files.

Many Thanks,
Dave.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below command to install the wine via terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Answer (score 1):

Install using `sudo apt-get install wine`

The website is at https://www.winehq.org/ with more information and hints on how to get individual windows programs working correctly under wine.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your very helpful responses. I have downloaded using the "sudo apt-get install wine" command. Towards the end of the installation a Microsoft message popped up asking me to acknowledge the end user agreement.This I tried but the message kept running. I tried to close but I was informed the download was still in progress. I waited a further 60 minutes and tried again. Still the same message? I eventually logged out. I searched under Dash home but could not see a download. I think it is downloaded but how can I check to see if it is please?  Regards, Dave.

Comment: Hi Ubuntu, I again tried to download wine. This time the first thing that happens is EULA pops up. At the top in red it says a reconfiguration is taking place. Unfortunately this seems to last a very long time before I eventually bomb out.

Comment: Whats the EULA for? .net?

Comment: David, the EULA is the "End user licencing agreement" by windows saying that if I use a windows program I am limited to the use of it? It seems to be stopping me downloading wine? I do not know how to by bass this?

Comment: I can attach screen print to show what I get. I am not sure how to do it? While the EULA is on screen the message at top says "configuring ttf-mscorefonts installer" While this is happening there is no movement on the hard drive and it goes on and on until I move from the page even though it says thing are being downloaded.

Comment: Those are the Microsoft core fonts that wine needs to emulate Windows programs. For somereason your system isn't downloading them properly. Try reinstalling them from the terminal: `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer --reinstall` then doing wine again. Mind you, are you able to accept the EULA? It's not stuck because you haven't accepted it?

Comment: Thank you David. I will try when I next get back to my wifi. I am most grateful for your explanation.

Comment: Got back to civilisation at last. Carried out the above instructions. All went well and the download carried through to the end. I looked under recently downloaded files but could not see Wine. How can I be sure it is downloaded please? Thank you.

Comment: If you ran this from the terminal, it should be installed. You should be able to see the wine command interface by opening the ubuntu program launcher and typing wine. See https://appdb.winehq.org/ for instructions on how to get your win application running with wine

Comment: David, you have been an unbelievable help to me. I want to thank you and the others who tried to help. I now have wine at long last. I do hope your kind instructions will be of help to others as well.